# GitHub Actions: Are there security concerns using an external action in a workflow job?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that FTPs files by using an external action from `someuser`:

```
    - name: ftp deploy
      uses: someuser/ftp-action@master
      with:
        config: ${{ secrets.FTP_CONFIG }}
```

Is this a security concern? For example could `someuser` change `ftp-action@master` to access my `secrets.FTP_CONFIG`? Should I copy/paste their action into my workflow instead?

Comment: I recently found this article with more helpful information: [Keeping your GitHub Actions and workflows secure Part 1: Preventing pwn requests](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `ftp-action@master` then every time your workflow runs it will fetch the master branch of the action and build it. So yes, I believe it would be possible for the owner to change the code to capture secrets and send them to an external server under their control.

What you can do to avoid this is use a specific version of the action and review their code. You can use a commit hash to refer to the exact version you want, such as `ftp-action@efa82c9e876708f2fedf821563680e2058330de3`. You could use a tag if it has release tags. e.g. `ftp-action@v1.0.0`
Although, this is maybe not as secure because tags can be changed.

Alternatively, and probably the most secure, is to fork the action repository and reference your own copy of it. `my-fork/ftp-action@master`.

Answer (score 1):

The [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#creating-and-using-secrets-encrypted-variables) does mention:

> Anyone with write access to a repository can read and use secrets.

If someuser does *not* have write access to the repository, there should be no security issue.

As commented below, you should specify the exact commit of the workflow you are using, in order to make sure it does not change its behavior without your knowledge.

Comment: I understand that others can't read my secrets directly. But I'm running my secret through someone else's code. What if that code changes? If their code sends my secrets to my ftp server, then could their code be changed (after it's incorporated into my workflow) to send my credentials elsewhere?

Comment: @sfmiller940 I will have to check but you should be using a specific version/revision of that code workflow: nothing should change unless you explicitly reference it.

Comment: So maybe I should specify the exact commit rather than just `ftp-action@master`?

Comment: @sfmiller940 Exactly: that would be safer